# Xpath only to the parent variable and not to the whole page

Tags: python, xpath, html-table, lxml

I am trying to get the data from a table and I am running into an issue where I have to get the data from a specific table data cell.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import urllib
from lxml import html

url="http://kforce.com/Jobs/Search.aspx?Location=&Specialty=Technology-Jobs&Keyword="

pageHtml = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

#id="Body_SearchResultsControl_grdJobs"

#row class jobResultsAlternateRow || jobResultsRowStyle

jobs = pageHtml.xpath("//table[@id='Body_SearchResultsControl_grdJobs']/tr[@class='jobResultsAlternateRow' or @class='jobResultsRowStyle']");

for i in jobs:
        cols = i.getchildren() #get all table data cells
        print(cols[0].xpath('//a/@href'))
        exit(0)
```

The xpath is being applied to all the links on the page and not just the column that I have assigned it to. I am not very familiar with XPath, but I am not sure if it is the XPath query or if it is my use of the xpath query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.//` if you want to start searching inside the element instead of the root:

```
print(cols[0].xpath('.//a/@href'))
```

Prints `['Job.aspx?job=1696~EQG~1259184T1~99&keyword=']` - I think this is what you wanted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ha! I will add that up over to my checklist. TY! I will choose this as the answer in 9 mins(Stackoverflow!!!!)